# Serialize array of LocalDate

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

What is the best of of serialising an array of LocalDate objects?

This is what I have:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate[] dates;
```

With my own custom deserializer which expects a single date. It throws this error:

> 2018-06-18T12:14:11.030+0100 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:384:
>   Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not
>   use numeric value accessors

Is there a quick way of getting this deserializer to work with an array?

Comment: its lame suggestion, but can you try with List<LocalDate>?, also make sure you extends `LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonSerializer<List<LocalDate>>`

Comment: you could create a `LocalDatesSerializer` which accepts an array rather than a single value